# SunOS 5.10 gives invalid terminal

Tags: terminal, solaris

While I login to SunOS 5.10 through putty it shows as

terminal vt100:

Then what ever command I type it says invalid terminal with the command.

For example if i type ls the display will be.

> invalid terminal ls

What is this issue? and how to resolve it? This was working fine earlier.

Comment: Looks like part of your PS1 prompt or PROMPT_COMMAND -- did either of those change recently?

Comment: I was testing telnet and nc commands. After that it went to this stage.

Answer (score 0):

If your `TERM` variable was not set, then Solaris commonly is configured to run `tset`, prompting you with its guess (usually preconfigured) what value of `TERM` would work, e.g., like this commented-out line (from `/etc/skel/local.login`):

```
#
# Copyright (c) 2001 by Sun Microsystems, Inc.
# All rights reserved.
#
# ident "@(#)local.login        1.7     01/06/23 SMI"
stty -istrip
# setenv TERM `tset -Q -`
```

In the question, it is suggesting `vt100`, and if you just press <kbd>*Enter*</kbd>, the shell will use `TERM=vt100`.

That prompt is not a *command prompt*, but used to get the `TERM` value.

For instance, you might have `TERM` set to `putty`, which is not in Solaris' terminal database, and triggered this behavior in your shell initialization.